# Converting $i$ to exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

How would I convert the irrational number $'i'$ to exponential form, or $e^{i\theta}$?

I'm working a little in De Moivre's theorem.

Comment: What would be the argument of $i$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @zzuussee it would be $\frac {\pi}{2},$ correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, a quarter turn to the left.

Comment: @zzuussee thank you! If I'm not mistaken it would just be $re^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$!

Comment: Yes, with $r$ being the length(distance) associated with it. What would be this in the case of $i$?

Comment: @zzuussee Just 1. The magnitude of $i$ is the distance from it to the origin, so we get $1$. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already shown the effort in the comments and found the solution yourself, I'll use the answer box to post a picture and elaborate *a little*:

[image]

The argument, the angle of the rotation between the $\mathbb{R}^2$-vector(associated with the complex number) is thus simply a $\pi/2$(or $90^\circ$) turn. As you've said yourself, the coefficient $r$ of the representation of a complex number using the complex exponential is the associated magnitude, i.e.

$$|i|=|0+1\cdot i|=\sqrt{0^2+1^2}=1$$

**Attribute for the picture:** By Original: GuntherDerivative work: Wereon - This file was derived from: Euler's formula.png:, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=821342